# Set default value with mat-select and formControl

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to set a default value to my formControl but seems not working.

**select-hint-error-example.ts**

```
export class SelectHintErrorExample {
  animalControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  selectFormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  animals: Animal[] = [
    {name: 'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'},
    {name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'},
    {name: 'Cow', sound: 'Moo!'},
    {name: 'Fox', sound: 'Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!'},
  ];
}
```

**select-hint-error-example.html**

```
<h4>{{ 'FormControl: ' + (animalControl.value | json) }}</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite animal</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="animalControl" required>
    <mat-option>--</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
      {{animal.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an animal</mat-error>
  <mat-hint>{{animalControl.value?.sound}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

**browser output**
[image]

I need to use formControl in my component, how do I set a default value?

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-select?file=app/select-hint-error-example.html) the stackblitz

## Update 1

Updated question structure with a better looking code snippets instead of images

Comment: You get an -1 from someone because of your images probably. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use object to set the the default value of select you have to use compareWith function.

> select supports compareWith input. compareWith takes a function
>   which has two arguments: option1 and option2. If compareWith is given,
>   Angular selects option by the return value of the function.

**component.html**

```
<h4>{{ 'FormControl: ' + (animalControl.value | json) }}</h4>
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Favorite animal</mat-label>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" [formControl]="animalControl" required>
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal">
            {{animal.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="animalControl.hasError('required')">Please choose an animal</mat-error>
    <mat-hint>{{animalControl.value?.sound}}</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
compareFn(cmp1,cmp2){
    return cmp1 && cmp2 ? cmp1.sound === cmp2.sound : cmp1 == cmp2;
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-form-select-yysajv)

[Reference](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#customizing-option-selection)

Answer (score 0):

For complementary the Chellapan answer, if you **don't want use compareWith**, you need put the "same object", some like

```
animalControl = new FormControl(this.animals[2], [Validators.required]);
//or
const animal=this.animals.find(x=>x.name=='Cow')
animalControl = new FormControl(animal, [Validators.required]);
```

Another aproach is that [value] was "animal.name"

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let animal of animals" [value]="animal.name">
```

And you can use

```
animalControl = new FormControl('Cow',[Validators.required]);
```

but you need create a function

```
searchAnimal(name)
{
   return name?this.animals.find(x=>x.name==name):null
}
```

if you want use

```
  <mat-hint >{{searchAnimal(animalControl.value)?.sound}}</mat-hint>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can seperate the declaration and instantiation of animalControl and set you default-value in the constructor or ngOnit.

```
export class SelectHintErrorExample {
  selectFormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  animals: Animal[] = [
    {name: 'Dog', sound: 'Woof!'},
    {name: 'Cat', sound: 'Meow!'},
    {name: 'Cow', sound: 'Moo!'},
    {name: 'Fox', sound: 'Wa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pa-pow!'},
  ];
  animalControl:FormControl;

  constructor(){
  this.animalControl = new FormControl(this.animals[2], [Validators.required]);
  }
}
```